# How to evaluate environment remote variables in SCP?

Tags: environment-variables, scp

Is there a way to have environment variables on a remote host evaluated when using SCP?

For instance, let's say I have `$FOO= /mydir` on host A; how would I do something like:

```
scp dogbert@hostA:$FOO/evil-secret-plans.txt .
```

Of course, `$FOO` isn't defined on my local machine so the above command doesn't work as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
scp dogbert@hostA:$(ssh dagobert@hostA "echo $FOO")/evil-secret-plans.txt .
```

A bit of overhead.

Comment: shouldn't that be `scp dogbert@hostA:$(ssh dagobert@hostA "echo \$FOO")/evil-secret-plans.txt .` (escaping `\$FOO`) ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `\`:

```
scp dogbert@hostA:"\$FOO/evil-secret-plans.txt" .
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier thing to do is to send the file with tar or gzip through stdout / stdin.

`tar -czf - ./evilsecretfile.txt | ssh user@remoteHost "cd \${varOnRemoteSystem} ; tar -xzf - ."`

or

`gzip -c localFileName.txt | ssh user@remoteHost "gzip -d > /remote/path/\${varOnRemoteSystem}  ; chmod 666 /remote/path\${varOnRemoteSystem}"`